# Unsupported lookup 'search' for django.core.exceptions.FieldError

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to do a **full text search** on my **postgres db** witn Django ORM like this:

```
Model.objects(column__search='value')
```

Unfortunately, this query results with this error:
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'search' for TextField or join on the field not permitted.`

How to fix that?

Answer (score 9):

The fix was simple. Django's `search` operator for postgres requires you to add `django.contrib.postgres` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your Django config file.